# Retrieving the images from the application's local folder

Tags: c#, uwp

I have take the screenshot and save them in application's local folder as jpg image. Now I want to retrieve these images in a list and bind with a listview in a class. please help me how I can do this.
I have save the images by this code

```
        var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(Window.Current.Content);

        //create unique file in LocalFolder
        var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("screenshotCapture.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

        //create JPEG image 
        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
            var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                    BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                                    (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                                    (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, logicalDpi, logicalDpi,
                                    pixelBuffer.ToArray());
            FileSavePicker filesave = new FileSavePicker();
            StorageFolder storagefolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var screenshotsfolder = await storagefolder.CreateFolderAsync("screenshotCapture", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            var Screenshot_image = await file.CopyAsync(screenshotsfolder, "screenshot" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".jpg");
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
```

now I want to fecth all the images from the local folder screenshots in a list.

Comment: What did you do? paste any your code and localize your problem and we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, it seems you have stored your screenshots in  "screenshotCapture" folder. So we can retrieve them like following:

```
var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("screenshotCapture");
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

Once we have these `StorageFile`s, we can use them to create `BitmapImage`s as the source of the `ListView` like:

```
ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> ImgList = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

foreach (var file in files)
{
    using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);

        ImgList.Add(bitmapImage);
    }
}
```

Following is a complete sample:

In XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ImgList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="BitmapImage">
                <Image Width="500"
                       Height="200"
                       Source="{x:Bind }"
                       Stretch="Fill" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

In code-behind

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> ImgList = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("screenshotCapture");
        var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);

                ImgList.Add(bitmapImage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```